# Salesforce @future not working

Tags: apex, trigger, future

I am sending the request to the docusign in salesforce apex triggers. The apex triggers call the external class and then the method call the http request. If I use the @future on top of the method,trigger will not call that method. I whitelisted the site url in the salesforce as well.
Below is the trigger code code

```
 HttpSend.callHttp(newUrl);
```

HttpSend class

```
global class HttpSend {
  @future
    public static void callHttp(String newUrl){
        try{
        System.debug('Http send called');
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint(newUrl);
        request.setMethod('GET');
        //request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
        //request.setBody('{"name":"'+newUrl+'"}');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('error in call  '+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@future` runs the code asynchronously (i.e. some indeterminate (but usually short) time in the *future*) as part of a separate transaction.

You wouldn't see it in the same debug log as where your trigger is run, but if you have a log trace set up for your user (or are using the developer console and are looking at the 'logs' tab) you should eventually see a separate log come up (with a type like "future", "futureContext", "futureHandler", or something along those lines).

It's this separate log that will contain the details of your callout.

#### +edit:

Also (as Kurunve reminds me), you need to set the `callout` modifier to be `true` (the default is `false`) in the `@future` annotation to allow callouts to be made. So use `@future(callout=true)`

Comment: in my opinion it is wise to mention that (callout=true) should be specified for future methods with callout

Comment: @kurunve Guess there's always something or other that I'm forgetting. Right you are. Edited.